# OpenVPN Network Unreachable

Tags: ubuntu, mac-osx, routing, openvpn

I'm working to set-up a VPN access to a group of virtual machines at Linode., the topology looks something like this:

`db.example.com       LAN: (eth0:0) 192.168.154.127/255.255.128.0
utility.example.com  LAN: (eth0:0) 192.168.164.229/255.255.128.0`

And, more servers on the LAN with addresses in the same range. The **utility** server is hosting the OpenVPN

Here's my server's OpenVPN configuration, the client configuration is not available as I'm using [Shimo](http://www.chungwasoft.com/shimo/) for OSX:

`dev tun
mode server
tls-server
proto udp
port 1194
server 10.77.22.0 255.255.255.0
push "route 10.77.22.0 255.255.255.0"
push "route 192.168.154.0 255.255.128.0"
ifconfig-pool-persist ipp.txt
persist-key
persist-tun
client-to-client
ca ca.crt
dh dh1024.pem
cert server.crt
key server.key
tls-auth ta.key 0
cipher BF-CBC
comp-lzo
user nobody
group nogroup
keepalive 10 120
status openvpn-status.log
verb 3`

When connected to the VPN, I can ping the VPN gateway, and log into it over SSH, and all normal operations without problems, `tcpdump` confirms that these packets are going over the `tun0` device on my Mac.

Attempting to ping `192.168.154.127` over the VPN doesn't work, `tcpdump` confirms that there's no activity on the `tun0` device.

I understand from reading [this](http://www.secure-computing.net/wiki/index.php/OpenVPN/Routing) that I need to add a `route` configuration to my `server.conf`, when adding the line:

```
route 192.168.154.0 255.255.128.0
```

the server throws an error when booting, inline here:

`/sbin/route add -net 192.168.154.0 netmask 255.255.128.0 gw 10.77.22.2
route: netmask doesn't match route address
Usage: route [-nNvee] [-FC] []           List kernel routing tables
       route [-v] [-FC] {add|del|flush} ...  Modify routing table for AF.`

```
   route {-h|--help} [<AF>]              Detailed usage syntax for specified AF.
   route {-V|--version}                  Display version/author and exit.

    -v, --verbose            be verbose
    -n, --numeric            don't resolve names
    -e, --extend             display other/more information
    -F, --fib                display Forwarding Information Base (default)
    -C, --cache              display routing cache instead of FIB
```

=Use '-A ' or '--'; default: inet
  List of possible address families (which support routing):
    inet (DARPA Internet) inet6 (IPv6) ax25 (AMPR AX.25) 
    netrom (AMPR NET/ROM) ipx (Novell IPX) ddp (Appletalk DDP) 
    x25 (CCITT X.25)

I suspect if I would resolve this `/sbin/route` problem, the situation would work as expected, but I don't understand why this is failing.

The client typically gets an address like this:

```
tun0: flags=8951 mtu 1500
    inet 10.77.22.6 --> 10.77.22.5 netmask 0xffffffff 
    open (pid 5142)
```

Comment: Is `ip_forward` enabled on the VPN server?  Do the firewall rules on the VPN server permit packets to be forwarded?  What IP address does your client get?

Comment: My client shows:

<pre><code>
tun0: flags=8951<UP,POINTOPOINT,RUNNING,PROMISC,SIMPLEX,MULTICAST> mtu 1500
 inet 10.77.22.6 --> 10.77.22.5 netmask 0xffffffff 
 open (pid 5142)
</code></pre>

I doubt `ip_forward` is enabled, strange that my client doesn't know even to send these packets over `tun0` though? Is `ip_forward` required? Firewall is disabled on the server for purposes of this test.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `route` statement in the configuration file needs to refer to the net id `192.168.128.0`, not `192.168.154.0`. `route` is barfing because you're giving it a network id and subnet mask than, when taken together, has 1's in the host id portion.

192.168.154.0 in binary is:

```
11000000.10101000.10011010.00000000
```

The subnet mask 255.255.128.0 looks like:

```
11111111.11111111.10000000.00000000
```

The subnet mask applied to the 192.168.154.0 "network id" looks like:

```
    11000000.10101000.10011010.00000000
AND 11111111.11111111.10000000.00000000
---------------------------------------
    11000000.10101000.10000000.00000000 = 192.168.128.0
```

You can see that 192.168.154.0 masked by a /17 subnet mask results in 1's after the end of the subnet mask. The net id of the 192.168.154.0/17 "network" is really 192.168.128.0/17. Change your `route` statement in the configuration file and the `route` command will stop barfing.

Comment: Thank you Evan! I have a further problem, `client/<CLIENT WAN IP>:40390 GET INST BY VIRT: <DB SERVER ON VPN LAN IP> [failed]` which I can't seem to resolve now. Thanks for the great answer though! (I actually understand how the CIDR notation works now!)

Comment: That problem was solved using `SNAT`, with: `iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -10.77.22.0/24 -j SNAT --to-source 192.168.128.0/17` on the VPN host machine (server).

Answer (score 1):

Enabling `ip_forward` is required.  A linux box will not route, unless it is.  On Ubuntu the an easy way to fix this is to adjust the /etc/sysctl.conf, just uncomment the ip_forward line.  Then reboot the system or run `sysctl -p`.

Comment: And my `route: netmask doesn't match route address` error?

Comment: He might be having a problem with IP forwarding, but he's got a route declaration there that's going to cause `route` to barf for sure.